# Reversing a Linked List Template Class

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse

I am trying to reverse a Linked List created using the built in Linked List class from java.  Is the below implementation something that is viable?  Moreover, in an actual software engineering environment would developers use the template class or their own?  Thanks!

```
LinkedList<String> example1 = new LinkedList<>();
example1.add("Ben");
example1.add("Sam");
example1.add("Kyle");
Object objectArr[];
String stringArr[];
objectArr =  example1.toArray();
stringArr = Arrays.copyOf(objectArr, objectArr.length, String[].class);
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArr));
Collections.reverse(newList);
example1.clear();
example1.addAll(newList);
```

Comment: If you just want to reverse your list, everything you need is calling Collections.reverse(example1).
If you want to copy that list and reverse the copy you should look at the available constructors:
LinkedList<String> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<String> list2 = new LinkedList<>(list1);
  
Collections.reverse(list2);

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure if you can answer the second bit, but do developers typically use template classes? or create their own?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the below implementation something that is viable?

Not really as you implemented it, because all you need to do in order to reverse a `LinkedList` object is invoking the `Collections.reverse(List<?> list)` static method directly without the need for creating two `arrays` and one `ArrayList` then rebuild the `LinkedList`.

> in an actual software engineering environment would developers use the template class or their own?

It depends on what you want to achieve, a neat way is use what Java provided to you and use the `reverse()` method. But if the performance is the issue

From Documentation (my emphasis):

> `public static void reverse(List<?> list)`
>   Reverses the order of the elements in the specified list. 
>   This method runs in **linear time**.

That means: the more the List grows, the longer is the time. So for example a list that contains 10 elements will take *two times* the time needed for a list with 5 elements and so on.

The question here is: can we improve the performance. I am not sure if I can answer this question properly, but I created a simple test to compare between 3 ways of reversing (*of course other users may have other improved ideas of how to reverse*), and here is the results:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListReversePerformance {

    static LinkedList<String> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    static LinkedList<String> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
    static LinkedList<String> list3 = new LinkedList<>();
    static long startTime, endTime;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // populate the lists, each with 1 hundred thousand item!
        for(int i =0 ;i<100000; i++){
            list1.add(String.valueOf(i));
            list2.add(String.valueOf(i));
            list3.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        // create temporary list
        LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<>();

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // run for loop to add the items from list1 to temp in reverse order
        for(int i=9999; i>=0; i--){
            temp.add(list1.get(i));
        }
        // clear list1 then add temp
        list1.clear();
        list1.addAll(temp);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Using For Loop and clearing old list: " + (endTime-startTime) + " Millisecond");


        // re-initialize temp and populate it again in reverse order
        temp = new LinkedList<>();

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=9999; i>=0; i--){
            temp.add(list2.get(i));
        }

        // re-initialize list2 and add temp using the constructor option
        list2 = new LinkedList<>(temp); 
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Using For Loop and reconstruct the old list: " + (endTime-startTime) + " Millisecond");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // use the reverse static method provided by Java Collections Class
        Collections.reverse(list3);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Using Collection.reverse(): " + (endTime-startTime) + " Millisecond");

    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Using For Loop and clearing old list: 875 Millisecond
Using For Loop and reconstruct the old list: 859 Millisecond
Using Collection.reverse(): 31 Millisecond
```

As you can see, `Collection.reverse()` still the fastest among them.
*As a result, I believe that Java provided best ways to reverse or sort in regard of the performance and memory.* 
But I'm still open to correction.